# How do I fix the loop cut eror "loop cut does not work well on deformed edit mesh display"?

Tags: modeling, bones

[image]

So, I'm trying to add a loop cut in the middle of the torso because the two bones on the torso weren't working properly, but I get the message "loop cut does not work well on deformed edit mesh display". Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to *Mesh > Face* menu and then select *Tri's to Quads* or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>J</kbd>. Should work after that = you can't make a loop in triangles...at least not the loop I think you are trying to make.

Answer (score 6):

It's not really an error, what you see is  just a warning that your mesh won't look like you want after a loop cut in a different pose since it's influenced by an armature.
you can delete the armature modifier temporarily and add it again after you do the cut to avoid seeing that message.